# Did Alain Finkielkraut say that "the left no longer has ideas, only enemies"?

Tags: quotes

A bunch of Spanish-speaking sites attribute (with slight variants) the following quote to French philosopher [Alain Finkielkraut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Finkielkraut):

> La izquierda ya no tiene ideas, sólo enemigos.

("The left no longer has ideas, only enemies.")

But... searching in French (Alain Finkielkraut gauche idées ennemis) and English (Alain Finkielkraut left ideas enemies) *nothing* similar appears.

The oldest reference I can find is this [2006 Spanish blog entry](http://blogs.libertaddigital.com/presente-y-pasado/el-nuevo-frente-popular-1031/3.html)

Answer (score 4):

Incomplete answer:

I found the disputed quote in [a list of quotations](http://sebastianurbina.blogspot.com/2013/04/rebuznos-de-la-izquierda.html), most of which I was able to trace to interviews published in ABC.es, libertaddigital.com, or *El Mundo* between 2006 and 2007. Of those three papers, I only have archives access to *El Mundo* from 2002-2019, and there is no interview with him in that time frame... but the quotation does appear in a [2019 opinion column](https://www.elmundo.es/baleares/2019/06/17/5d0762a621efa0ba3c8b4608.html) in *El Mundo* which is certified by [The Trust Project](https://thetrustproject.org/)!

Since the list of quotations puts Finkielkraut next to Bernard-Henry Lévy, I wonder whether it is older than the rest, e.g. from the 1980s when they were both appearing as Zionist "new philosophers" in the European press.

Comment: The three sources are highly questionable. Libertad Digital is a mix of alt-right and dogmatic libertarianism. ABC was a respectable conservative newspaper, but today is firmly in the (Trump-style) hooligan right. And about  El Mundo... see https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/sep/15/media.pressandpublishing.

Comment: I've searched at https://www.abc.es/hemeroteca/: (https://www.abc.es/hemeroteca/alain+finkielkraut+izquierda+ideas+enemigos). Only two hits  without the supposed quote...

Comment: I found several interviews with Alain Finkielkraut in the correct time frame and all of them were, as you say, full of highly questionable statements. This one was really something http://questionscritiques.free.fr/edito/haaretz/finkielkraut_171105.htm